# Rotate text / Vertical text in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I need vertical text or just a way to rotate a ColumnText in ITextSharp.

(It needs to be absolute position)

Until now i have tried a lot of diffrent solution, but with no luck.

Here is a couple of tries:

1.

```
_cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12f);
_cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "Hello World", 50, 50, 90);
```

2.

```
var vt =  new VerticalText(_cb);
vt.SetVerticalLayout(50, 50, 400, 8, 30);            
vt.AddText(new Chunk("asdasd",_sf.ChildBackPageTextOneFont()));
vt.Go();
```

3.

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix foo = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
foo.Rotate(90);
_cb.ConcatCTM(foo);
```

I have also tried to draw it with System.Drawing.Graphics, but the quality is VERY poor.

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

Use something like this:

```
Imports System.Drawing, System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Dim transf as new Matrix
transf.RotateAt(30,New PointF(100,100), MatrixOrder.Append)
writer.DirectContent.Transform(transf)

transf.Invert()
writer.DirectContent.Transform(transf)
```

Rotate the canvas, write some text, rotate it back.

Comment: "...and rotate it back".  You could also call `directContent.saveState()`, transform and draw your text, and then call `directContent.restoreState()`.  Less work for the computer, less bytes in your content, and not subject to floating point math errors that might grow larger as you transform things back and forth and back and forth.

Comment: writer.DirectContent.SaveState();writer.DirectContent.Transform(transf);DrawSomething();writer.DirectContent.RestoreState();

Answer (score 14):

I have tried a lot of methods from the web for this rotate issue. But none of them worked. Finally I figured out a simple solution. Maybe we can do it like this. We can draw a table with no borders, and just with one cell. And we add text in the cell, finally rotate the cell.
Every is ok then.

```
        table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.TotalWidth = 72;
        paragraph = new Paragraph("123");
        cell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
        cell.Rotation = 270;
        cell.BorderWidth = 0;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 72, 72, writer.DirectContent);
```

Besides, the WriteSelectedRows method can position this cell.

Comment: That is a very nice answer and it is even possible to use alignment for the cell like "cell.HorizontalAlignment = PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER". Also the font can be set for the paragraph like this "new Paragraph("123", <your font>)".

Comment: I used cell.Rotation = 270 to make cell text vertical. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the easiest way is similar to your first try. You just needed to add a call to **BeginText()** and **EndText()** like this

```
_cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(), 12f);
_cb.BeginText();
_cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, "Hello World", 50, 50, 90);
_cb.EndText();
_cb.Stroke();
```