# How to rotate text in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, text, itext, rotation

I have searched the web but it looks like that it is not that easy, how can i rotate my text?

```
Document doc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(600, 800), 0, 0, 0, 0);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/genpdf.pdf", FileMode.Create));

doc.Open();

iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file);
Chunk c1 = new Chunk("~Comment~"); //rotate 270°

doc.Add(image);
doc.Add(text);

doc.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389261/rotate-text-vertical-text-in-itextsharp

Comment: @Samich I have found this article myselfe but it wasen´t the answer i was looking for :-(

Comment: How comes it's not the answer you're looking for? It answers the question "How to rotate text in iTextSharp"

Comment: I have no idea there the writer is coming from..

Comment: In case you haven't figured it out yet, `PdfWriter.GetInstance()` returns a `PdfWriter` object so use `PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/genpdf.pdf", FileMode.Create));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in [Rotate text answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4397552/707458)

The writer is a PdfWriter type, you can get it like:

```
using (stream = new FileStream(temp_filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
```

Comment: Nice, but the link you refer to is the same one @Samich posted over an hour and a half before this...